# A RegEx for Expressions starting with $

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a Expression ($ASMLNA$ * $TSM$ * 8 * ($GrossDownTarget$ * $005930K$)+15)

Now I am trying to get all the variables which is between $ $. Example $ASMLNA$ so for me it should give ASMLNA.

I have tried using RegEx and this is what I have been able to do till now

```
  Regex r = new Regex(@"[^\$]");

        string Contents = txtRegEx.Text.Trim();
        MatchCollection ImageCollection = r.Matches(Contents);
        string tempContents = string.Empty;
        foreach (Match match in ImageCollection)
        {
            tempContents+= match.Value;
        }
```

It will be great if someone can point me in correct direction.

Comment: What makes you think that you need to use a regular expression here? Why not just iterate over the string one character at the time and save the begin and end positions into one `LinkedList<int>` (or you can have two: one for begin, one for end) and then do whatever other magic through regex-free code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=\$)\b[^$]+\b(?=\$)
```

If your variables can only contain word chars (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), this regex would be better:

```
(?<=\$)\w+(?=\$)
```

Comment: This will also return the strings between - for example - the second and third `$`, will it not?

Comment: @exhuma: I believe you are right, I updated it with `\b` which seems to be valid given the example data above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression only matches a $ at the beginning of the string.  To get groups, I think you want something like this:   @"(\$.+?\$)"

**Edit:** Oops.  I missed the bit about stripping out the $.  Try this version instead: \$(.+?)\$